Why is QValidator not working with the mask
The validator and the mask I set seem to conflict somehow. The validator and mask are to manage a line edit, to have a HH:MM format. The mask giving the : and the validator to ensure a real time was inputted. I am aware that there is a QTimeEdit, but from what I saw, I didn't like the design, and it didn't seem to support 24h clocks.
ui->Time1->setInputMask("00:00");
QRegularExpression timeRegex("^(?:[01]\\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\\d$");
QRegularExpressionValidator *timeValidator = new QRegularExpressionValidator(timeRegex, this);
ui->Time1->setValidator(timeValidator);

Expected result: Inputting 0759 should appear as 07:59, result:  : , literally no input allowed.
I'm not sure if it's because I'm doing something wrong, or if my regex is broken. I'm using QRegularExpressionValidator because that was listed as the preferred method in Qt5+.
From my testing, they individually work perfectly fine, but seem to prevent me from typing anything when combined.
Test cases:
Input for all cases: 0

Removed : from both validator and regex.
Result, build succeeded, but no inputted numbers appeared on the line edit.

Removed ^ and $ from regex.
Result, build succeeded, no inputted numbers appeared on the line edit.

Changed mask from 00:00 to 99:99.
Result, build succeeded, no inputted numbers appeared on the line edit.

Moved setting the mask below the validator, only mask worked.

Removed mask: Validator works, and the regex enforces a pattern.

Removed validator: Mask works, and the pattern is present.



Is there any reason for not using QTimeEdit with an appropriate setDisplayFormat()?
